# Read short data from binary file using CArchive class in C++

Tags: c++, file, buffer, short

I have created an application that store `short` array into a file.using `CArchive class`

**Code to Save Data**

```
CFile objFile(cstr, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
CArchive obj(&objFile, CArchive::store);

obj << Number;  //int
obj << reso;    //int
obj << height;  //int
obj << width;   //int
int total = height * width;
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    obj << buffer[i];//Short Array
```

This is code snippet which I use to save data in file.

Now I want to open that file using `CArchive`.

I have tried to open that using `fstream`.

```
std::vector<char> buffer(s);
if (file.read(buffer.data(), s))
{

}
```

But the above code don't give me same data what I save. So, can anyuone tell me how I can get that data in `short` array using `CArchive` or any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the buffer is an array of SHORT, the code to load data can be written as :

```
CFile objFile(cstr, CFile::modeRead);
CArchive obj(&objFile, CArchive::load);

obj >> Number;  //int
obj >> reso;    //int
obj >> height;  //int
obj >> width;   //int

int total = height * width;

//release the old buffer if needed... e.g: 
if( buffer ) 
    delete[] buffer;

//allocate the new buffer 
buffer = new SHORT [total];

for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    obj >> buffer[i];
}

obj.Close();
objFile.Close();
```